# How to give forward declaration of a object type in class B if it declared in class A by make use of "using" keyword

Tags: c++, boost

Following is my original code

```
class m_VertexProps;
class m_EdgeProps;
class m_GraphProps;
using m_graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, 
boost::bidirectionalS,// Vertex Properties...
                                 m_VertexProps,
                                 // Edge Propereties...
                                 m_EdgeProps,
                                 // Graph Properties
                                 m_GraphProps>;

class A{
public:  
   A();
   m_graph g;
 };
```

Now I want to give forward declaration of m_graph in class B. I don't want to include class A in class    B's header file. I will include it in .cpp file.
How can I give forward declaration of m_graph class;
I tried in following way but didn't work.

```
 class m_graph;
 class B{
     public:
         B();
    };
```

Comment: Post code as text instead of as image.

Comment: Now I want to give forward declaration of m_graph in class B. I don't want to include class A in class    B's header file. I will include it in .cpp file.  
How can I give forward declaration of m_graph class;
I tried in following way but didn't work.

Comment: _"... I tried in following way but didn't work...."_ but the code shown in the last example will compile ok. Please post a [mcve] that illustrates the problem: - live - https://godbolt.org/z/3687jqcx7

Comment: You cannot forward declare an alias... You have to copy paste the alias or include where it is declared.

Comment: You could have a `blah.h` with the `using m_graph...` and then include it from both `A.h` and `B.h`. I would recommend putting `m_vertexProps`, `m_EdgeProps`, ... within a namespace `blah` in `blah.h` (`blah` meaning whatever appropriate name you decide).

Comment: Hi @rturrado, If I use blah.h for using m_graph and if I include blah.h in other file then it is give duplicate declaration error

Answer (score 1):

The goal as posed in the title is impossible: you *cannot* use `using` to cause a forward declaration¹.

However, what I *think* you are running into is a frequent problem when declaring BGL graphs with property bundles, when you need the graph traits inside the property bundles.

The trick is to use traits on the "base graph" inside your properties.

E.g.:

```
using BaseGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS>;
using Traits = boost::graph_traits<BaseGraph>;
using VD = Traits::vertex_descriptor;

struct VertexProperties {
     std::string metadata;
     VD predecessor; // no forward declaration required!
};

struct EdgeProperties {
     double weight;
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS,
        VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;
```

### Compilation Firewalling

If you really only want the properties to hide implementation details, just use the [Pimpl Idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) like you would anywhere else.

> Note it implies that you cannot have template interface in your public header, unless it doesn't depend on the complete types of the implmentation.

## Bonus Technique

As a bonus, if you want to completely forward declare the graph and only use them by reference or as return value in the header, you can use this trick:

```
struct Graph; // forward declare
```

And then at the implementation site:

```
struct Graph : boost::adjacency_list</*...*/> {
    using base_type = boost::adjacency_list</*...*/;
    using base_type::base_type, base_type::operator=;
};
```

For things to work well, you might need to implement delegating friends, and perhaps delegating traits:

```
template <> struct boost::graph_traits<Graph> :
    boost::graph_traits<Graph::base_type> {};
```

---

¹ ignoring useless tricks like `using _dummy = std::hash<struct Y>;` - which *does* technically forward declare `Y`, but it adds no value over *just* `struct Y;`

Comment: Added a final trick that sometimes helps  out - I don't really recommend subclassing BGL graph models (because they weren't designed for it) but in some situations it might give you the most effect for the least effort.